# JPA EclipseLink ManyToMany with Data

Tags: orm, jpa, many-to-many, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I'm currently trying to implement a ManyToMany Relationship with Data in the JoinTable.
I'm following [this approach](http://boris.kirzner.info/blog/archives/2008/07/19/hibernate-annotations-the-many-to-many-association-with-composite-key/)  with the Eclipselink JPA Framework.
But I'm getting the following exception:

> org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:210)
>       ... 23 more
>   Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7298] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.1.v20100817-r8050): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
>   Exception Description: The mapping [group] from the embedded ID class [class de.kapieren.mbm.server.model.UserGroupPK] is an invalid mapping for this class. An embeddable class that is used with an embedded ID specification (attribute [pk] from the source [class de.kapieren.mbm.server.model.GroupMembership]) can only contain basic mappings. Either remove the non basic mapping or change the embedded ID specification on the source to be embedded

Does anybody know whats the meaning of basic mappings in relationship to embeddedId?
What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EclipseLink is complaining about the use of non `Basic` mappings (for example a `ManyToOne`) in an `Embeddable` class used as a primary key (i.e. annotated with `EmbeddedId`).

And according to the JPA 2.0 specification, this is indeed not supported:

> #### 11.1.15 EmbeddedId Annotation
>
> The `EmbeddedId` annotation is applied
>   to a persistent field or property of
>   an entity class or mapped superclass
>   to denote a composite primary key that
>   is an embeddable class. The embeddable
>   class must be annotated as
>   `Embeddable`. **Relationship mappings
>   defined within an embedded id class
>   are not supported**.

If I rephrase, the `EmbeddedId`'s `Embeddable` class must define each id attribute for the entity using `Basic` mappings in standard JPA.

#### References

- JPA 2.0 Specification

  - Section 11.1.15 "EmbeddedId Annotation"